# install Oracle jdbc driver in Apache Geronimo

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, osgi, geronimo

I tried to install Oracle JDBC driver to Apache Geronimo without success. I'm using **ojdbc6.jar**.

I copied it to the repository folder and tried to setup, first an Oracle XA pool using Geronimo's Admin console, without success. It complained that the driver was missing with a ClassNotFoundException for OracleDataSource.

Then I tried to setup a regular Jdbc Driver (oracle thin). I wrote user/pass/sid etc and managed to succeed a ping to the database. Then when I saved this connection pool, it complained again with a ClassNotFoundException, this time for *oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver*.

What can I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

http://oss.org.cn/ossdocs/geronimo/development-deployment/database.html - Section 6.1. JDBC Drivers - has an example for oracle driver.